# How to pass R variables as input to SearchES method in ElasticSearch?

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am working with RElasticSearch package in R. I am able to connect to the proper index in ElasticSearch. Suppose my index contains two fields like id and name. Two of my R variables,say rid and rname contains the value i want to search. How should i use the searchES method to accomplish this? I have tried using like:

```
searchES(server=es.index,query="id":rid & "name":rname)
```

but it keeps throwing an error! Can someone please help me out?

Comment: It's helpful to share the exact text of error messages when you encounter them.

Comment: And your syntax (ie the `searchES` funciton) doesn't look the example functions on https://github.com/duncantl/RElasticSearch. Where are you reading your documentation?

Comment: But maybe `query=paste0("id:", rid, " AND name:", rname)` is what you need

Comment: Thanks a lot!! paste command worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly build your as a character value in order for this to work. In order to concatenate strings in R, you should use `paste()`. For example

```
searchES(server=es.index,query=paste0("id:", rid, " AND name:", rname))
```